How to label a HFS/HFS+ partition?
I try to use e2label to label a HFS/HFS+ partition:
sudo e2label /dev/sdc9 "Test(HFS)"

But get the error: bad magic number
I am using ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64

Adding Ubuntu version info would go a long way to offering you any help.

@David, Just add the info. Thanks.

Please read man e2label, this command is meant for ext2, ext3 or ext4 partitions, not for hfs. Currently relabeling doesn't seem to be supported by the tools provided by the hfsprogs-package, only during creation of a new filesystem you can deifine a label.

@mook765, OK. I see. Thank you.

I’m voting to close this question because information available through man page
